# Code inside the firebase listen function does not execute immediately

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, listen

I am trying to listen for database changes and update my datas.But the problem is that the function doesn't enter immediatly inside my `for` loop and my function always return me null.Have you some ideas?

```
Future<InfoCompagnie> getPlace(
      {String compagnie,
      String dep,
      String arr,
      String jour,
      int nbrPlace}) async {
    var infoCompagnie = InfoCompagnie().obs;
    db
        .collection('PLACE')
        .document(compagnie)
        .collection('$dep-$arr')
        .document(jour)
        .collection('Bus')
        .where('PlaceDisponible', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 2)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
        .listen((document) {
      for (var data in document.documents) {
        if (data.exists) {
          codeBus = data.data['CodeBus'];
          infoCompagnie.update((value) {
            value.accessiblePlace = accessiblePlace;
          });
          return infoCompagnie.value;
        } else
          return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Listeners do not trigger immediately.  They are asynchronous, and will trigger whenever data is first becomes available.

Comment: OK@DougStevenson .It means that I can't make it synchronous using `async-await` keyword?

Comment: Listeners do not return a Future, so they are not compatible with await.

Comment: OK @Doug Stevenson.I find a way to achieve that.Please check in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers activation depends from different kind of situtaions for example, on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Firestore loads data asynchronously, since it may take some time for this.

If you want to understand better how works, check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

As explained in this [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) you can write asynchronous code using futures with 'async' and 'await' keywords.

If you need to manage synchronized operations, you can find useful examples at this [document](https://pub.dev/packages/synchronized), for example:

```
import 'package:synchronized/synchronized.dart';

main() async {
  // Use this object to prevent concurrent access to data
  var lock = new Lock();
  ...
  await lock.synchronized(() async {
    // Only this block can run (once) until done 
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: OK@Harif Velarde .It means that I can't make it synchronous using `async-await` keyword?

Comment: This is what am looking for.Thanks  @Harif Velarde